# dumpsys SurfaceFlinger output interpretation

Tags: android, surfaceflinger, dumpsys

Recently, I have started using `dumpsys SurfaceFlinger` to gather some information about android graphics. I currently work on a development board called Odroid-XU3. The display is a Dell monitor which is connected to the board through HDMI cable.

In the very last few lines of the output of the above command, I have two displays, while I only expect to have one. One of them is `Display[0]` and the other one is `Display[1]`. The `type` column of each of the displays could be `HWC` or `GLES`. Some times they are both HWC or GLES and some other times one is HWC and the other one is GLES.

What is the difference between Display[0] and Display[1]?
I have tried to find a documentation to understand how to interpret the output of the aforementioned command, but I have not found anything useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would help to have the dumpsys output in your question, but I can make a couple of general observations.

`display[0]` is the device's built-in display. `display[1]` is an "external" display, in your case HDMI.  These two indices are hard-wired.  (Well, they were as of KitKat; I don't know if they've since un-hard-wired things.)  Virtual displays start at index 2.

The chunk of text below the display is the hardware composer dump.  It displays the layers on the screen, with a bunch of information about the position, rotation, and format of each layer.

The closest thing to documentation can be found in the HWC section of the [graphics architecture doc](https://source.android.com/devices/graphics/arch-sv-glsv).  Given the level of the system you're working with, I would recommend you read the entire document.  Beyond that, you can try to discern the meaning from the [source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/native/+/lollipop-release/services/surfaceflinger/DisplayHardware/HWComposer.cpp#1119).

The arch doc does explain the difference between "HWC" and "GLES" in the output: "HWC" means the surface lives on a display overlay, while "GLES" means the surface is being composed with the GPU instead.

Comment: Display[1] is indeed for the external display. I just unplugged the display and only see Display[0] in the output. The only problem is that my board does not have any other display, e.g. I can only see the UI through my external display. So I'm not sure what Display[0] corresponds to.

Comment: When I last looked at SurfaceFlinger, it was really determined to have a "primary" built-in display. This didn't make sense for various applications (like TV set-top boxes), but the assumption was wired in. I don't remember if there's overhead incurred from unnecessary composition on the non-existent display -- if the Surfaces are "GLES" it may be composing them with the GPU.

Comment: It might be producing unnecessary output.